# CSS not loading when site is accessed over HTTPS using an Apache reverse proxy server

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu, https, proxy

Thanks in advance for any help!

I'm running Ubuntu 13.1 on an EC2 instance. My app is written in Node.JS (based off NodeBB) and I'm using Apache 2 as a reverse proxy server to establish a secure connection on port 443.

The problem is that when I visit the website via HTTPS, none of the CSS is rendered!

My browser registers a number of errors of these 3 types:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Proxy Error) 
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Here's my config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName forum.ligma.com
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/forum_ligma_com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/.ssh/myserver.key
   SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/combined-ca.crt
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    <Proxy *>
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</IfModule>
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4568
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4568
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas what's going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: what have you set for max concurrent connections in apache?

Comment: No idea. Can you tell me how to check that? :)

Comment: MaxClients in apache2.conf

Comment: The string "MaxClients" doesn't appear in that file...

Comment: search for MPM and post, what you find. My suspicion is, that the number of concurrent proxy processes is too low, so that some requests  can't get a ride

Comment: Thanks for trying to figure this out! Neither term is in the file. I haven't tested it with multiple browsers trying to access the site. The main problem is that the CSS and JavaScript files aren't loading. Everything else seems to be working fine.

Comment: The error message, "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" is a JavaScript error message, suggesting that the issue is in the JS/node code. Are you able to provide any relevant logging output from that application?

Comment: Looks like Require.js couldn't be loaded -- try accessing it directly by querying `/vendor/requirejs/require.js`. Also try running NodeBB in development mode: `./nodebb dev`